# Subversion post-commit hook will not run on commit, script works because I can run it on the command line

Tags: bash, svn, hook, post-commit-hook

I have just made a new repository. My server is Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit. 
I want my commits to be live as soon as I have committed them. This is achieved by making a working copy in my public html directory, and having the post-commit hook update that working copy. I have set that up using the instructions here:

http://www.frenssen.be/content/using-subversion-automatically-update-live-website

The issue is that my post-commit will not run when my project commits. **My project commits just fine**. I know that the script is a valid script too, because I can run it with

```
env ./post-commit
```

inside of the `hooks` directory and it properly updates.

I thought it might be a permissions thing so I have made extensive use of `chown` to ensure that `www-data` is the owner of:

```
the repo /home/svn/repo2
the working copy /var/www/html
the hook /home/svn/repo2/hooks/post-commit
the update binary /home/svn/autoupdate/autoupdate
```

But still nothing. My commits are successful, but the hook never runs. My hook script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
/home/svn/autoupdate/autoupdate
```

All of the googling seems to be pointing to a permissions issue but I can't figure this one out.

Comment: Nope, sorry I did not clarify that very well in the question. Project commits just fine, I can commit it, then run my post-commit in the console manually and it works as expected

Comment: If you add another line of code to the hook (before the autoupdate) .. does that execute? (trying writing to /tmp or something)

Comment: i inserted `mkdir /tmp/hello` and nothing happened

Comment: You've listed your chowns, but how about your modes? (in particular, does post-commits have the appropriate eXecute mode set?)

Comment: I have tried 744 and 755 and 777, all have the same result

Comment: Do you know of maybe an error log I could `tail` that would be logging the failed attempts of the commit action to call the post-commit hook?

Comment: That works! After playing around with everything, I think an issue that was happening was that my call to `svn update` was prompting for a password which the `post-commit` of course could not provide, so I have hard-coded by login info to the script, and now everything is working. `If your post-commit hook actually failed, I think you would see evidence of that in whatever client you were using to perform the checkin` That definitely helped narrow down the culprit. Thanks for your time!

Comment: That's awesome to hear. Nice job providing a good writeup initially. I've moved my relevant comments down into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you repeat this guy's example, and see if it works at all? 
[mikewest.org/2006/06/subversion-post-commit-hooks-101](http://mikewest.org/2006/06/subversion-post-commit-hooks-101)

**Do you get an error when you commit?**

If your post-commit hook actually failed, I think you would see evidence of that in whatever client you were using to perform the checkin. I'm almost suspecting that post-commit is not firing at all. Just to double check, the file needs to actually be called post-commit, all lowercase, and not post-commit.tmpl.

Comment: Knowing that an erroneous script would break the commit enabled me to trace the fact that the script was running, just not doing what I was expecting. Seeing that when I ran the script manually, it was asking me for credential's for the repo, I could piece together that the post-commit was running but just not providing the correct credentials. Thanks again!